# c# Entering data from list into Access Database with foreach results in duplicated values in all rows

Tags: c#, ms-access, foreach, commandparameter

I am attempting to input a list from C# to an Access Database. However when it get input all of the rows have the exact same values. I can do a console write in the for each and show that it is getting the correct values, it's just writing the same thing over and over. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Here is the code and screenshots,

```
    public static void BuildMerakiTemplateList(string client, IList<MerakiApi.ConfigTemplates> templateList)
    {
        using (
            var conn =
                new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" +
                                    @"Data Source=" + UniversalVariables.ConfigShare + @"CustomerLanInfo.accdb")
        )
        {
            OleDbCommand cmd = null;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into [Meraki Templates](ClientID, TemplateName, TemplateID) values (?, ?, ?)", conn);
            conn.Open();
            foreach (MerakiApi.ConfigTemplates template in templateList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(template.name + " " + template.id);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ClientID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = client;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TemplateName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = template.name;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@TemplateID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = template.id;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
    }
```

[Console output of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0P0d3.png)

[View of entries in database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Qb4.png)

Comment: Create and add parameters once outside of the loop, then only assign parameter values inside. As it is now, you create a lot of parameters, but only the first 3 are used and of course have one and the same values in every command execution.

Comment: @IvanStoev That is exactly what is was lol, after I sent in the question I realized what I was doing and could do nothing but shake my head. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a string to use a SQL with parameters, you don't use `?` as the command parameter name, you need to pass the `@paramName` - with a `@` sign:

```
cmd = new OleDbCommand("INSERT into [Meraki Templates](ClientID, TemplateName, TemplateID) values (@ClientID, @TemplateName, @TemplateID)", conn);
```

Then, when you add the command parameters, you add the parameters **wintout** the `@` sign:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("ClientID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = client;
cmd.Parameters.Add("TemplateName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = template.name;
cmd.Parameters.Add("TemplateID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = template.id;
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```